# How can I change the playback speed on SoundCloud?

Tags: soundcloud

A podcast I listen to releases their episodes early on SoundCloud. I'd love to be able to listen to the podcast at 1.25x speed or 1.5x speed.

Normally, I'd just use some JavaScript to [change the playback speed of the `audio` element](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23618973/3023052):

```
document.getElementById("audio1").playbackRate=1.25;
```

However, when I look for `audio` or `media` elements on the page, I'm not able to find any. I'm assuming that the audio is played through some JavaScript that doesn't insert one of these elements on the page. I know that there is an `.mp3` file being streamed because I can see an `.mp3` file being streamed in the Network tab of Chrome.

The `.mp3` file is coming from `https://cf-hls-media.sndcdn.com/media/{id}/{id}/{filename}.128.mp3` with a query string consisting of `?Policy=...&Signature=...&Key-Pair-Id=...`. If I open one of these requests, it shows a 9 second clip of the file. Deleting these parameters in the request give me a `Forbidden` message.

I would be interested in either:

- Pulling up the SoundCloud audio file directly in the browser so I can set the playback rate there
- Finding a way to use JavaScript to modify the playback rate of the SoundCloud audio file

Is there any way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 4):

The [Global Speed extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/global-speed/jpbjcnkcffbooppibceonlgknpkniiff/related?hl=en) was able to change the speed on Soundcloud.  It should be available also for Firefox.  I tried several other extensions which were unable to speed up Soundcloud.

Answer (score 0):

I got a little excited with trying to reverse engineer this, when really there's a simple way to work around this.

On the SoundCloud page for the podcast audio file, there's a download button. I can download this file, open it up in the browser, and it loads up with a `video` element. I can then directly set the `playbackRate` of that `video` element using:

```
document.querySelector('video').playbackRate = 1.25
```

Comment: I do not see a download button on sound cloud.

Comment: @MicahZoltu - The help says you have to be logged in to download, and also "Not all tracks are downloadable."